# how do I change hungggrrrrryyyy = hungry and other such english words

Tags: nlp

The problem is simpler to understand, but I think is difficult to solve. Given a word how to form a proper english word. example:

```
hunggrrryyy to hungry  
awweeeeseom to awesome  
frusstrated to frustrated  
looooooove  to love
```

Are there any known solutions to such problem?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean deleting duplicate letters (which do occur in the English language) or kicking letters out of a string until it becomes a word?

Comment: If it was only for repeated characters, you could of course just create variations of the string in which you remove some of them and do a dictionary lookup. The "-seom" part of "awweeeeseom" however makes it more complicated. Could you identify the set of misspellings you expect to encounter? Like (1) repeated characters, (2) transposed characters, (3)... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably could use a similar tack to what Peter Norvig did with [this spell checker](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html).

At the very least you'll need some context checking.  Does "loooooooooser" map to "looser" or "loser" within a particular phrase?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, google can do it.  My guess is you need a bunch of data to do this.

If you can use a service, googles service might do it for you... it has spelling correction.
http://code.google.com/apis/soapsearch/reference.html

Comment: Tying in loooooooooooooove won't search for love, it'll search for loooooooooooooove. I'm not sure this is really what he needs.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you could reduce all repeats of more than two letters. I'm pretty sure there are no english words with any 3 consecutive repeats.

This reduces:

hunggrrryyy to hunggrryy
awweeeeseom to aweesome
frusstrated to frusstrated (no change) 
looooooove  to loove

You are then likely to have more success with traditional spell-checking approaches.

Since you know you are looking for duplicates, you could also generate all the variants by turning the duplicates into single letters:

hunggrryy  -> hungrryy, hungryy, hungry etc

and see if one of then matches a dictionary lookup. Note that you may get false positives for similar words like lose, loose; son, soon

Comment: My scrabble word list includes BRRR and ZZZ.

Comment: Fair point - my Oxford English Dictionary has brrr but not zzz. You could handle these as special cases if you really want to ;-)